# Error related to \usepackage{graphicx}

Tags: graphics, packages

I am getting the following errors after TexStudio and MikTex updates.

1. Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage error, and,
2. Missing number, treated as zero. \usepackage in **\usepackage{graphicx}**

I am writing my thesis and am stuck on these issues. Please help !!!!

Comment: You need to include more information like TeXstudio, MikTeX versions and a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) i.e. code showing your packages, document class etc. Without that information, your question is probably too vague

Comment: do you have `\usepackage{gensymb}` on the line above?