# TexMaker giving ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage error when installed on a new computer

Tags: errors, conditionals, miktex2.9

I installed MixTex and TeXMaker on new my new computer and I started getting the following error. My code compiles fine on the old computer and on overleaf. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling couple of time but didn't work. It gives an error for all packages not only for "enumerate". Even gave error on an empty line. Any ideas?

Error Message:
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

v
l.6 \usepackage
{enumerate}
I was expecting to see `<',` =', or `>'. Didn't. ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> v l.6 \usepackage {enumerate} A number should have been here; I inserted` 0'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this happen with literally every document? Post as minimal as possible a document that produces errors like this, as well as the .log file that gets generated, and also tell us exactly what you're doing in texmaker to compile the document.

Comment: texmaker is just the editor so not involved here. Check your log is this from `gensymb`  package?

Comment: same as this I guess https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661934/error-related-to-usepackagegraphicx#comment1646627_661934

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon sir, don't know if this can help you or not.

I did update miktek packages today and opened the file I was working on yesterday, I was getting the same error while generating the pdf.

It was package "gensymb" fault. I was using it for \degree command, resolved not loading it and switching to ^{\circ}

Best things,

A.M. MEng

Comment: note gensymb is already fixed at source on ctan so should be fixed at a miktex update shortly

Comment: Yes, it was due to MixTeX. I uninstalled it and installed Tex Live Manager and everything started working again.