# Error seemingly related to \usepackage{gensymb}

Tags: packages

Using TexStudio 4.3.1 and MiKTeX 4.8 (MiKTeX also reports all packages up to date), I get the following two errors:

- Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \usepackage
- Missing number, treated as zero. \usepackage
  similar to this question:
  [Error related to \usepackage{graphicx}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661934/283542)
  The highlighted line is `\usepackage{esint}`, however if I comment out the previous line `\usepackage{gensymb}`, the build succeeds. This seems to be in line with what David Carlisle commented on the aforementioned unanswered question, but I'm not sure what the actual issue is. `gensymb` appears to be installed according to MiKTeX. Here is my attempt at a MWE (bear with me):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gensymb was broken it has been fixed at source but I don't know if it is on miktex yet

Comment: @DavidCarlisle seems not to be there yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gensymb has been fixed at source and in texlive but apparently not yet in miktex.

You could fix a local copy, just add a missing `/13` as shown in the last commit in the sources:

https://gitlab.com/kjhtex/gensymb/-/commit/7eae952310598e5c402aaf5377cb0979534a9a01

so it look like

```
\ProvidesPackage{gensymb}
  [2022/10/13 v1.0.1 (KJH)]
```

Comment: Thanks David, could you point me towards resources for how to implement a local copy of the package so I could fix it? I'm not familiar with that method as I've just had MiKTeX handle everything for me until now.

Comment: your log file will show the full file path to gensymb.sty copy that file to the folder with the document then edit as shown. But I would guess it gets updated at miktex soon (or you could report it there to give him a nudge) @jjbloon